# How do you print certain amount of results in range by user input using python?

Tags: python

I was trying to create a dice rolling program where the user enters how much a certain amount of dice they want to roll. But it is not working. What should I do?

```
from random import branding
repeat = True
while repeat:
    amount = input('how many dice do you want to roll?')
    for i in range(0, amount):
       print("You rolled",randint(1,6))
    print("Do you want to roll again?")
    repeat = ("y" or "yes") in input().lower()
```

Comment: Aren't you getting an error? Do you understand the error?

Comment: BTW, the last line should be `repeat = input.lower() in ('y', 'yes')`

Comment: `amount` is a string, the argument to `range()` has to be an integer.

Comment: What is `branding`? That should be `randint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 4th line, you just did `input()`. However, you need to add an `int()` function around the input.

This would be your code:

```py
from random import *
repeat = True
while repeat:
    amount = int(input('how many dice do you want to roll?'))
    for i in range(0, amount):
       print("You rolled",randint(1,6))
    print("Do you want to roll again?")
    repeat = ("y" or "yes") in input().lower()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this language, but I love it and I bet you do too, hence I put together an idea based on your code, I certainly hope this answers your question. Keep coding bro, Python is great!

```
#First, you only need the random function to get the results you need :)
import  random
#Let us start by getting the response from the user to begin
repeat = input('Would you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')

#As long as the user keeps saying yes, we will keep the loop
while repeat != 'n':
# How many dices does the user wants to roll, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5  who knows. let's ask!
    amount = int(input('How many dices would you like to roll? \n'))
# Now let's roll each of those dices and get their results printed on the screen
    for i in range(0, amount):
       diceValue = random.randint(1, 6)
       print(f"Dice {i+1} got a [{diceValue}] on this turn.")
#Now, let's confirm if the user still wants to continue playing.       
    repeat = input('\nWould you like to roll the dice [y/n]?\n')

# Now that the user quit the game, let' say thank you for playing
print('Thank you for playing this game, come back soon!')
# Happy Python Coding, buddy! I hope this answers your question.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're importing `branding` from the `random` module, not `randint`.
2. Use `int()` when calling the `input()` function, for the `range()` function to work properly.
3. In the last line, `repeat = ("y" or "yes") in input().lower()`, `("y" or "yes")` will evaluate to a boolean, and then your check will become something like `True in input().lower()` which gives incorrect, and bizarre results. Use something like `repeat = input().lower() in ("y", "yes")` instead.

Comment: You are correct, but the OP doesn't use the branding module in his code anywhere.

Comment: My point is, he doesn't even import the 'randint' function anywhere, so the code will break because of that.

Comment: That's also true.